# Set runtime input possibility in python?

Tags: python, input, printing, set, runtime

I am trying to get and print the runtime input for set in python.

```
l1=set()
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    l1.update([])
print(l1)
```

The above code doesn't produce any output. Some of you give example how to get runtime input for a set and how to print the values

Comment: What do you mean by "runtime input"? Do you mean to take input in the for loop itself and then update the set with that input?

Comment: Did you want `l1.add(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list because a set will remove all the doubles, and adding some values to add.

```
l1=list()
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    l1.extend([8])
print(l1)
```